# Intercepting Wget output

Tags: bash, wget

I have a .php file that I would like wget to download, it will display a 4 digit number. Is there anyway to retrieve this output without wget echoing to an external file, and then reading the external file and deleting the external file.

Something like..

```
OUTPUT=`wget www.google.com`
print $OUTPUT
```

where it would get the text of google.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using UNIX?  You can tell wget to be quiet (i.e. not print status info) and pipe the document to stdout easily:

```
wget -q -O /dev/stdout <URL>
```

(note that's a capital letter "O")

Not sure of a Windows way, but this means you get just the HTML document written to stdout, which you can then use within scripts...

Comment: You can use `-` instead of `/dev/stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

curl will do what you want out of the box:

```
OUTPUT=$(curl www.google.com)
echo $OUTPUT
```